# Arrays.asList() method behaves differently

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8

In the code below, why do line 3,4 print different things ?

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a)); // prints the address
System.out.println(b); // prints the content
```

Comment: Compare what `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)` vs. `Arrays.asList(a)` does.